# Better subsetting and counting values in a dataframe

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data frame with two columns and 70,000 rows.  One column serves an identifier for a household, column `b` in the example below.  The other column refers to the individuals in the household, numbering them from 1 to n with some error (could be 1,2,3 or 1,4,5), column `a` in the example below.

I'm trying to use hierarchical clustering with the number of individuals in a household as a feature.  The code I've written below counts the number of individuals in a household and puts them in the proper column and row, however takes several minutes with the actual data set I have, I assume due to its size.  Is there a better way of going about getting this information?

```
fake.data <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,5,6,7,1,2,3,1,2,4), b = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"))
fake.cluster <- data.frame(b = unique(fake.data$b))
fake.cluster$members <- sapply(fake.cluster$b, function(x)     length(unique(subset(fake.data, fake.data$b == x)$a)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is quicker, but you could use `dplyr` in various ways. One approach: get the distinct rows and then count `b`.

```
library(dplyr)
fake.cluster <- fake.data %>%
  distinct() %>%
  count(b)
```

Comment: you are my hero

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(fake.data)[, .(members = uniqueN(a)), b]
#   b members
#1: a       4
#2: b       3
#3: c       3
```